# How to specify search option with MS graph java SDK

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-graph-api

```
IMessageCollectionRequest eventRequest = graphClient.getGraphClient().users(user.getEmail()).messages()
                .buildRequest(new HeaderOption("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type=\"text\""))
                .select("body,subject,toRecipients,ccRecipients,CreatedDateTime,conversationId,from");

IMessageCollectionPage eventPage = eventRequest
                                  .filter(filter)
                                  .get();
```

In the above code I am able to get results based on specified filter.

Now I want below **search** to be performed insteat of **filter** as MS graph does not support both of these to be applied.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserId}}/messages?$search="recipients:@xyz.com"](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7B%7BUserId%7D%7D/messages?$search=%22recipients:@xyz.com%22) & $top=1000

How can we specify search condition instead of filter. exactly shown in the above URL usig java SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `options` in `buildRequest`.

```
LinkedList<Option> requestOptions = new LinkedList<Option>();
requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$search", "\"recipients:@xyz.com\""));

MessageCollectionPage messages = graphClient.users("{UserId}").messages()
    .buildRequest( requestOptions )
    .top(1000)
    .get();
```

Comment: I tried tis one. I am getting below Exception.
com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: BadRequest
Error message: Syntax error: character ':' is not valid at position 10 in 'recipients:@xyz.com'.

Comment: @Sadashiv The value must be surrounded with double quotes. Updated the answer.